# azure blob uploadfile bad request

Tags: azure-storage

Hi I am new to azure I am trying to upload a file to azure container using

```
    static void UploadBlobFromFile(Uri blobEndpoint, string accountName, string accountKey)
    {
        // Create service client for credentialed access to the Blob service.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient =
            new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint,
                new  StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey));

        // Get a reference to a container, which may or may not exist.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("StackOverflowAnalysis");

        // Create a new container, if it does not exist
        //container.CreateIfNotExist();

        // Get a reference to a blob, which may or may not exist.
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("QueryResults.csv");

        // Upload content to the blob, which will create the blob if it does not already exist.
        using (var filst = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"c:\users\hmohamed\Downloads\QueryResults.csv"))
        { blob.UploadFromStream(filst); }
    }'
```

I am getting  error Bad request 400; I am trying this in mvc app I have also tried it with console application where i got error the process cannot access file because it is being used by another process. Responses to similar posts advice to run netstat command to fix the problem but I do not know how to use it and what parameters to supply; can some one please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All letters in a container name must be lowercase. So, please use "stackoverflowanalysis" as your container name.

For more information on naming, please refer to [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx).